# Edit as HTML in IE for Style Element

Tags: internet-explorer, dom, internet-explorer-11, web-inspector, ie11-developer-tools

I am not sure why `Edit as HTML` of `<style>` element is disabled in IE 
However, I can edit as HTML of the `<style>` element in Chrome. 
How to enable it?

[image]

Comment: If you think that selecting the specific element and try to modify the CSS using the styles tab can help to edit the CSS for the IE then you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your IE might be outdated or isn't a compatible version checkout https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_browsers.html it's generally used in modern-day browsers for enabling writing content directly inside of web pages or online applications. Its core code is written in JavaScript and it is developed by CKSource.

Answer (score 1):

I try to check the **Edit as HTML** option and it looks like IE does not support editing the CSS using this option. This is the reason that the **Edit as HTML** option is disabled for style elements.

However, if you select any specific HTML element on the page using developer tools then you can see the applied CSS in the **Styles** tab that gets displayed in the right sidebar of the developer tools.

Here, you can add, edit, or delete the CSS elements.

See here:

[image]

References:

1. [Editing elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/elements#editing-elements)
2. [Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/elements/styles)

Note: You may notice that the above document links for the Edge legacy browser, but both the MS Edge legacy browser and IE browser use the same developer tools. So this information also applies to the IE browser.